# how to solve errors in apt-get update in ubuntu

Tags: apt

I am new to Linux and i cannot correct this error which i am facing in Ubuntu 16.04. I feel that my question is different than the other questions involving `apt-get update` because the situation differs. My system information is as follows:

```
Linux PcAbdurraheem 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Whenever I type the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'mono-xamarin.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Can anyone please help me. I was trying to run the following command after which the error occurred to do programming in Visual Basic when this error occured:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.listsudo
```

Comment: You have a sudo which fails with a "permission denied".  That is rather worrying.  Could it be that /var is on a read-only filesystem?  What does "mount" show?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille he mentioned being new to linux, so I find that rather unlikely. He clearly named the source.list file wrong and I assume one of his attempts messed up the procedure.

Comment: @rwenz3l You may very well be right, but it could be you are wrong (in this case).  I don't remember ever having had an apt session stuck, but I've only been using Linux for 20 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> N: Ignoring file 'mono-xamarin.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

clearly indicates that the filename is wrong:

```
# Goto directory:
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
# fix the name:
mv mono-xamarin.listsudo mono-xamarin.list
```

> [..] Operation not permitted

and

> E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

as well as

> [..] 13: Permission denied

**indicates that you are not root** *OR* the apt-get process is already running, but failed and left an unclean state behind.

check for running apt-get processes:

```
ps -A | grep apt
```

you should see something like this:

```
8737 pts/7    00:00:00 apt-get
```

where **8737** is the process that is stuck
if you see multiple processess, kill each of them with:

```
sudo kill <process>
```

check back if the process is still there. If you can not terminate the process this way, use:

```
sudo kill -9 <process>
```

after that you have to cleanup the apt-get lockfiles:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

finally to the desired update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Sources: [tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-lock/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have some broken things there. Try this: wget -q -O - NAME_OF_MISSING_WHATEVER sc | apt-key add - to add it. Also what's the latest action(s) that you/someone else did there before this happened? Is this the first time ever on that OS that you did apt-get update (did it ever work before)? If you just installed your distro of Linux it could be that you need to re-download the *.ISO file, then check for MD5 value to verify that it matches and if you burn it to CD/DVD make sure you use CD/DVD burning software with ability to verify that ISO was written properly (i added this since you you're new to Linux).

Comment: Yes @Frido-X this apt-get update has worked before but, as I stated in my original question that after entering the command:

Comment: Well then something or somebody wrecked your OS. I'm sure that looking at *.log files can't hurt -- look at log files (including old files) from the time when you know all worked fine to the latest logs from today. That might give you a clue what went wrong, @A.Farooqui.